# How to copy data from txt file and paste to XLSX as value with Python?

Tags: python, excel, txt

How to copy data from txt file and paste to XLSX as value with Python?

(txt)File: simple.txt which contains date,name,qty,order id
I need the data from txt and copy paste to xlsx as VALUE.

How it's possible it? Which package could handle this process with Python?
openpyxl?Panda? Could you please give an example code?

My code which not suitable for the paste and save as values:

import csv

import openpyxl

input_file = 'C:\Users\mike\Documents\rep\LX02.txt'

output_file = 'C:\Users\mike\Documents\rep\LX02.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

ws = wb.worksheets[0]

with open(input_file, 'r') as data:

```
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')

for row in reader:

    ws.append(row)

wb.save(output_file)
```

Comment: Please show us how your data looks: what is inside the txt file and what structure is?

Comment: And moreover, please tell us what you did already and what you encountered. I could find 2 relevant packages with 1 simple google search.

Comment: Why don’t you take a look at [comma-separated values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) (CSV) which is what most spreadsheets are. Python supports CSV out of the box. Plenty of examples there, too…

Comment: Ladies and Gents, I need a code which suitable for the next : copy txt.value , open excel application, paste as value  and save workbook.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, with [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) combined, you can store the content of a comma delimited `.txt` file in an `.xlsx` spreedsheet by running the code below :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

input_file = r'C:\Users\mbalog\Documents\FGI\LX02.txt'
output_file = r'C:\Users\mbalog\Documents\FGI\LX02.xlsx'

pd.read_csv(input_file).to_excel(output_file, index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not work because the mentioned txt contains empty columns and rows.

Comment: That's not what is said in your question. You said *(txt)File: simple.txt which contains date,name,qty,order id)*. Can you share a sample of your `.txt` file ?

Comment: This txt came from SAP transaction (LX02)